# Airflow docker on EC2: webserver not approachable and components won't turn to healthy status

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, airflow

I'm running airflow docker container at ec2 instance(t3.large).
it's purpose is to get data from one database(postgresql) to another database(redshift).

this airflow container works at local PC well.
however, it doesn't work at EC2(though, approaching to EC2 had no problem at all.).

to make airflow docker container, I've got docker-compose.yaml from official site.
(curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.1/docker-compose.yaml')
and fixed it(at x-airflow-common passing .env file, put 'build:' to use dockerfile which is for adding python dependency, prevent loading example dag, 'volumes:'-because company asked me to put docker-compose file at the root of project directory).
volume options I've wrote at docker compose file

```
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

I copied my dockerfile, dag(and required source code), docker-compose.yml,etc through git to ec2.
ofcourse docker installed(version 20.10.17).

and ran it with these commands(yes, I modified name, because there was another docker-compose.yml file already).

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.etl.yml up airflow-init
docker-compose -f docker-compose.etl.yml up -d
```

and my result is airflow webserver not approachable.

[my docker ps result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgAbJ.png)
unlike running this docker at my local environment top 4 docker components doesn't turn to healthy status.
and therefore webserver and other airflow function isn't working at all.

[this console log is what I've got from docker logs airflow-worker id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMVSl.png)

[last log screen from airflow-scheduler id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfBKt.png)

[last log screen from airflow-webserver id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8j7P.png)

[last log screen from airflow-triggerer id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5NIy.png)

there are my dag options I gave at my dag.py

```
@dag(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="my_process_v01.00",
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
    catchup=False,
    description="move data from A to B",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 5, 10),
    schedule_interval="0 */12 * * *",
)
```

Thank you very much for reading my question.
and thank you for your knowledge sharing.

Comment: have you set AIRFLOW_UID and gave permissions to the volumes?

Comment: @ozs
I've set AIRFLOW_UID at .env

howenver I haven't gave any permissions.
what should I do?

Comment: i would start with "chmod 777 -R directory_path" and if it helps then modify after to less permissions

Comment: @ozs you mean these right?
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/packages/etl_processor/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

Comment: right, those volumes

Comment: @ozs wow, your answer was what I should have done. Thank you very much!!

Comment: great, I wrote an answer for that, please mark it as good. 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Permission to your volumes.

start with `chmod 777 -R your_directories` and if it works you can modifed it later to less permissions